# JTable into JScrollPane, without Header

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtableheader

Why there comes tableHeader automatically when I add a `JTable` into a `JScrollPane`. I want to add table into a scrollPane without header. How to do? Pls

Comment: [dup](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25059277/2587435)

Comment: In your previous question, people asked for an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You should have edited your post with one, and someone would have reopened your question, instead of posting another question with even _less_ information. Don't know what you're expecting. As others have said, the code you provided doesn't cause the NPE, that's why we need runnable code to test it out

Comment: table.setTableHeader(null); works the same ways as JScrollPane.setColumnHeaderView(null); no idea why is there NPE in your case , sure is the JTable intialized

Comment: use JTable.setTableHeader(null); only,

Comment: I reopened this question since for some reason people closed his other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25059277/removing-header-of-a-jtable).

Answer (score 4):

Short answer is, you can't (do it automatically).

What you can do is call `JScrollPane#setColumnHeaderView` and pass it `null` after you've set the `JTable` to the viewport...

The column headers are applied to the `JScrollPane` by the `JTable` when the tables `addNotify` method is called.  This is called in response to a container, which contains the table, been added to a displayable container (like a visible frame).

This then calls `configureEnclosingScrollPane`

**Updated**

The above code assumes that the `JScrollPane` and `JTable` have already been added to a container that is already displayable, this may not always be the case.  You could, alternatively, override the `JTable#configureEnclosingScrollPane` method and configure the headers when you want them to be...

```
@Override
protected void configureEnclosingScrollPane() {
    if (showHeaders) {
        super.configureEnclosingScrollPane();
    }
}
```

Now personally, I would create my own custom `JTable` which had a `showColumnHeaders` property and which could used to toggle the headers on and off based on my needs...

Comment: if (getAutoCreateColumnHeader() && isDisplayable()) { then configureEnclosingScrollPane();

Answer (score 3):

Try next code:

```
    JTable t = new JTable(3,3);
    JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(t);
    t.setTableHeader(null);
    jScrollPane.setColumnHeaderView(null);
```

or just setting tableHeader to null works for me `t.setTableHeader(null);`